# Question about connecting to an IPFS API

Tags: support, specific-question, scope

Asked this question today

[IPFS API - connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70334109/5675325)

but seems to be getting some dispute as to whether this is programming related or not - and I can't see the end of it.

How to proceed in this case?

Comment: Saying why you think it's programming related might be a good start.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I believe it's programming related because I don't see a non-programmer setting up an IPFS server node on an Ubuntu server and try connect with it through an API

Comment: You wouldn't see this as a devops/sysadmin kind of thing then?

Comment: Did you already check the help center of serverfault.com if this on topic there? (I'm not a SME in this, so no idea if this would fit the scope)

Comment: "I don't see a non-programmer setting up an IPFS server node on an Ubuntu server and try connect with it through an API" My ops colleagues do things like that all the time. I can assure you that "non-programmer" is a fitting term in many cases...

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I did that and was to stash my pony pics.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I posted these as comments on your question in main, but I'll repost them here as an answer:

Since you got a "connection refused" and never got to the API itself, this seems like a Super User or Networking issue.

> [*from comments*] I got to the API if I curl from within the server. It's only when I try from my local machine that it doesn't work

That seems only to reinforce the point. The HTTP API works, but there seems to be a networking issue.

> [*from comments*] I don't think this to be a Super User question because I don't see a non-programmer setting up an IPFS server node on an Ubuntu server and try connect with it through an API

It doesn’t matter. It’s not about the API. Again, as yourself pointed out, the HTTP API works. You simply have a connection issue. This is a networking issue unrelated to your specific use case (connecting to an API).

---

Basically, you've already verified that the HTTP API works correctly by being able to connect to it locally using cURL. The API works and it's listening to HTTP commands as it should.

You've encountered a connection problem when issuing the same commands from your computer to the server. It looks like there is a connection/firewall issue, which you have correctly pinpointed by doing some basic debugging.

This is not a programming issue, nor it's actually topical to the API you want to use. I don't think the question is on-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I've asked in DevOps based on the clarification from @RobertLongson - https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/15108/20375

Comment: No idea if it's on-topic on DevOps.se. At first sight, I'd say it's not, but don't know much about that site.